# OpenLayer unable to add feature with custom graphic to layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to add a marker with a custom graphic to my map, but I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'vectorLayer.addFeatures')

My code for adding the marker looks like this

```
function addMarker(id, lat, lon, orientation){
    var ll = new OpenLayers.LonLat(Lon2Merc(lon), Lat2Merc(lat));
    var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(ll.lon, ll.lat);

    var style_mark = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
    style_mark.graphicWidth = 24;
    style_mark.externalGraphic = "/icons/myicon.png";

    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, null, style_mark);
    vectorLayer.addFeatures([ feature ]);
}
```

I initialized the 'vectorLayer' like this:

```
vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( 'Vector Layer', { styleMap: olStyleMap });
map.addLayer( vectorLayer );
```

To me it looks like the `vectorLayer` does not have a method called addFeatures. I assembles my code by combining [this](http://www.codechewing.com/demo/add-icon-to-geometry-point-openlayers/) and [this](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/vector-features.html) (Openlayer Example code). The actual exmaple code does have a lot of overhead, but I'm not quiet sure which part I can leave out. I'm greatful for any help.

Comment: Look at line 540 here: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector.js. Vector Layers have an addFeatures method. Is vectorLayer in scope within addMarker? Ultimately, hard to tell without a working code sample.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem, the vectorLayer was out of scope, I fixed it and now its working